# wordpress php > div issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Thanks in advance for you help > Ive been doing this as a lovejob for friends and now I'm getting quotes of several hundred dollars for minor homepage variation and I'm not sure if its valid. I'm not a programmer myself, just trying hard.

Via the CafePress press75 theme, I'm trying to go from 1 / 2 / 3 column home layout, to 1-2 merged and 3,  push the 2nd column data to the right and have the 1st column span as a 16:9 gallery (nextgengallery plugin installed).

Is this really a complex thing from a coding perspective?  The current guy talking to me is saying its going to cost $700 or 800 AUD to alter, which is rough when the template cost $85..

From this: http://shocolate.com.au.previewdns.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/shocolatecurrent.jpg

to this: 'url+Shocolatelooklikethis.jpg'

I was able to get the sidebar removed by taking out ‘‘ near the bottom of home.css.. Just can’t get the middle data to flow over it?  This would be ideal as a result, as the system puts the latest selected blog post on the homepage, so if we can get rid of the sidebar div and have the text appear where it was, that would be ideal.

Removing the sidebar from the bottom of home.php and setting the thumbnail width to say 450 gives me the result im after EXCEPT the text doesn’t fill where the sidebar is, it wraps underneath.

Reference 'shocolate.com.au.previewdns.com' for current site

Comment: I'm confused, but are you making the edits, doing it for a client, or is someone bidding $700 to you? This isn't a big deal since it requires moving a few things around and including a nextgen gallery. You might even want to think about using a page template.

Answer (score 0):

I am making the edits and was seeking external assistance due to being stuck, where I was told it may be like several hours work..  Handily the general support community came through, was only a quick edit;

I replaced content in home.php

```
<div id="main" >
            <div class="postbox">
```

With

```
<div id="main" class="home">
            <div id="home" class="postbox">
```

Added this to style.css

```
#content .home, #home{width:100%;}
```

Works like a charm.

If I can close this question I would :)